# Calling a .c file from MATLAB yields a segmentation violation

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I want to run a two C programs called "hello1.c" and "hello2.c" from matlab.

**My `hello1.c` code is as follows:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mex.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "matrix.h"


void funcc(double **f, double **x, long n, long b, double lambda, double theta)
{
    long i;
    long j;
    double u,v,y,z,w;
    y = theta*lambda;
    w = lambda*lambda;
    z = 0.5*(theta+1.0)*w;

    u = 0.0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<b;j++)
        v = fabs(x[i][j]);
        if (v <= lambda)
            u += lambda*v;
        else if (v > y)
            u += z;
        else
            u += 0.5*(v*(2*y - v) - w)/(theta-1.0);
        }
    **f = u;
    return;
}


void mexFunction (int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{
    /*set up input arguments */
    double **x       =            mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    long     n      =      (long)mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
    long     b      =      (long)mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);
    double  lambda  =            mxGetScalar(prhs[3]);
    double  theta   =            mxGetScalar(prhs[4]);
    int     type    =       (int)mxGetScalar(prhs[5]);

    double **f;


    /* set up output arguments */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);

    f=mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    funcc(f, x, n, b, lambda, theta);
    }
```

**My `hello2.c` code is as follows:**

```
long mymin(double *x, long n)
{
    long i, ind;
    double temp;
    temp = x[0];
    ind = 0;
    for (i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (x[i] < temp)
        {
            ind = i;
            temp = x[i];
        }

    }
    return ind;
}


        void funnn(double *x, double *d, long n, long b, double lambda, double theta)
        {
            long i;
            long j;
            double u,z,w;
            double xtemp[3],ytemp[3];
            z = theta*lambda;
            w = lambda*lambda;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<b;j++)
                u = fabs(d[j*n + i]);
                xtemp[0] = min(lambda,max(0,u - lambda));
                xtemp[1] = min(z,max(lambda,(u*(theta-1.0)-z)/(theta-2.0)));
                xtemp[2] = max(z,u);

                ytemp[0] = 0.5*(xtemp[0] - u)*(xtemp[0] - u) + lambda*xtemp[0];
                ytemp[1] = 0.5*(xtemp[1] - u)*(xtemp[1] - u) + 0.5*(xtemp[1]*(-xtemp[1] + 2*z) - w)/(theta-1.0);
                ytemp[2] = 0.5*(xtemp[2] - u)*(xtemp[2] - u) + 0.5*(theta+1.0)*w;
                x[j*n + i] = xtemp[mymin(ytemp,3)];
                x[j*n + i] = d[j*n + i]>= 0 ? x[j*n + i] : -x[j*n + i];
            }
            //return;
        }



        void mexFunction (int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
        {
            /*set up input arguments */
            double* d       =            mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
            long     n      =      (long)mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
            long     b      =      (long)mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);
            double  lambda  =            mxGetScalar(prhs[3]);
            double  theta   =            mxGetScalar(prhs[4]);

            double *x;


            /* set up output arguments */
            plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n,b,mxREAL);

            x=mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

            funnn(x, d, n, b, lambda, theta);
        }
```

The problem is that when I compile my MATLAB code in which it calls my C functions (of course I have already written `mex hello1.c` and `mex hello2.c`), MATLAB returns me the screen which exhibits that MATLAB has encountered an internal problem and needs to close. In fact this error was detected while a MEX-file was running.

Is this because my functions `mexFunction` are not written correctly? Can anyone who knows how to write MEX functions help me?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: You could try to write a very easy Hello Word .c file and see if the problem persist when calling it from Matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `hello1.c`, [`mxGetPr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetpr.html) in MEX does **not** give you a double pointer.  It gives you a **single** pointer and for 2D memory, it is in a column-major layout. You have to access the right value in the 2D array by the following syntax, given that `i` and `j` are the row and column in the 2D array you want to access:

```
ind = j*rows + i;
```

... and thus if you want location `(i,j)` in your 2D array `x`, simply do:

```
double val = x[j*rows + i];
```

`rows` is the total number of rows in your 2D array.  As such, you will have to correct this in your code to be able to access the 2D array properly.  You'll also have to do the same for `f` as well.  In addition, you're missing a pair of curly braces around the second `for` loop and I'll explain why later.

Therefore, your function becomes:

```
void funcc(double *f, double *x, long n, long b, double lambda, double theta) // Note change in function declaration
{
    long i;
    long j;
    double u,v,y,z,w;
    y = theta*lambda;
    w = lambda*lambda;
    z = 0.5*(theta+1.0)*w;

    u = 0.0;
    // n is the rows, b is the columns
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<b;j++) { // Added
        v = fabs(x[j*n + i]); // Change here
        if (v <= lambda)
            u += lambda*v;
        else if (v > y)
            u += z;
        else
            u += 0.5*(v*(2*y - v) - w)/(theta-1.0);
        } // Added
    } 
    *f = u; // Change
    //return; // Superfluous
}
```

Your `mexFunction` now becomes:

```
void mexFunction (int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{
    /*set up input arguments */
    double *x       =            mxGetPr(prhs[0]); // Change
    long     n      =      (long)mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
    long     b      =      (long)mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);
    double  lambda  =            mxGetScalar(prhs[3]);
    double  theta   =            mxGetScalar(prhs[4]);
    int     type    =       (int)mxGetScalar(prhs[5]);

    double *f; // Change

    /* set up output arguments */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);

    f=mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    funcc(f, x, n, b, lambda, theta);
}
```

For `hello2.c`, everything is fine except for the second `for` loop. You simply need to surround the code block with curly braces:

```
           for(i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
                for(j=0;j<b;j++) { // added
                u = fabs(d[j*n + i]);
                xtemp[0] = min(lambda,max(0,u - lambda));
                xtemp[1] = min(z,max(lambda,(u*(theta-1.0)-z)/(theta-2.0)));
                xtemp[2] = max(z,u);

                ytemp[0] = 0.5*(xtemp[0] - u)*(xtemp[0] - u) + lambda*xtemp[0];
                ytemp[1] = 0.5*(xtemp[1] - u)*(xtemp[1] - u) + 0.5*(xtemp[1]*(-xtemp[1] + 2*z) - w)/(theta-1.0);
                ytemp[2] = 0.5*(xtemp[2] - u)*(xtemp[2] - u) + 0.5*(theta+1.0)*w;
                x[j*n + i] = xtemp[mymin(ytemp,3)];
                x[j*n + i] = d[j*n + i]>= 0 ? x[j*n + i] : -x[j*n + i];
                } //added
            }
```

The reason why you need the extra braces for both files is because if you omit them, C only considers the first line after the loop to be the loop body. The rest of the code after the `for` loop finishes is executed and not part of the loop which is the reason why you're getting segmentation faults.

Comment: Hello dear rayryeng. I would like to thank you so much for your help!! please I just have one other problem. I edited my question in which I have added a hello2.c code. I applied your suggestions in hello2.c but I am still getting a segmentation violation. BTW the function hello1.c works well now thanks to you!! :)) Any other help from you will be very appreciated!!

Comment: Hi there. You should check if your function in hello2.c is correct. For example, I don't see a reason why xtemp and ytemp is declared. You're doing computations and storing them in those variables but they're not being used for the output array. Also check your statement when assigning to x at the end of the loop. To me it's not doing anything meaningful. I'll wait until you verify if this is the code you want before editing my answer.

Comment: OK I'll have a look soon.

Comment: Figured it out. Look at your second for loop. There are no curly braces that surround that block of code.

Comment: Yes!! it works now! BTW in hello1.c I didn't put a curly braces for the second loop. So why I should for hello2.c ?? Anw thank you a lot sincerely! You are the best

Comment: Not using curly braces means the for loop will only execute the next statement for the loop. The rest of the code is not in the loop.

Comment: @Christina You're very welcome. I've edited my answer to make this clear for you

Comment: I spent about 6 hours to resolve hello2.c (just after I recieved your answer for hello1.c). But it is weird that I didn't expect to add a a second curly braces for the second loop. Okay I am new in C language:)

Comment: Ah got it. Actually you need braces in the first version too. I didn't catch that one.

Comment: Changed. Have a look at the first one now.